# pysvn file copy function in revision

Tags: file, tortoisesvn, copy, revision, pysvn

I use pysvn 1.7.5 to access my svn server.
If I want to copy a single file from a svn Server to my local disk there are no pysvn function implemented. But if I make a connection by https I can copy the single file, without doing a hole checkout on a directory.

```
def fetch_svn_file(self, file_url, local_path):

    local_path = local_path.replace('\\', '/')

    # Set up a HTTPS request with username/password authentication
    try:
        # create a password manager
        password_mgr = HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()        

        # Add the username and password.
        password_mgr.add_password(None, 'https://www.xyz.com', self.default_user, self.default_passwd)
        opener = build_opener(HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr))
        remote_file = opener.open(file_url)

        content = remote_file.read()     

        try:
            local_file = open(local_path,"w")
            local_file.write(content)
            local_file.close()
        except IOError:
            return -1

    except URLError, e:     
        print 'URLError: "%s"' % e
        return -2

    return 0
```

The same way tortoise do it, if i drag a file from the Retro browser to my local disk, but tortoise can also copy single files in another revision. Anyone now how I can realise this in pysvn or in simple python code?? If these function is implemented by tortoise it has to be possible in pysvn too... because of the same developer team.

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer. :-)

there is a standart pysvn function called "pysvn.export". The name was so strange for a copy function....